# How to send Artifactory publish credentials from buildscript without hardcoding them?

Tags: security, gradle, artifactory

Take this snippet from a Gradle build for instance:

```
repository {
   repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
   username = 'whatever'
   password = 'whatever123'
}
```

In the past, I've configured Maven (some setting under `~/.m2`) to simply pass username/password along. If at all humanly possible I'd like to avoid putting my login credentials for our Artifactory server inside a buildscript. Is there a more secure workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can put a `gradle.properties`file into your ~/.gradle/ folder.

In this file you can put your credentials:

```
artifactoryUserName = whatever
artifactoryUserPassword = whatever123
```

now you can reference these properties in your build script:

```
repository {
    repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
    username = project.hasProperty('artifactoryUserName') ? artifactoryUserName : ''
    password = project.hasProperty('artifactoryUserPassword') ? artifactoryUserPassword : ''
}
```

Comment: And if they are not found in the properties file (since you are running the build on a build server, for example), you can fall back to environment variables :)
`username = project.hasProperty('artifactoryUserName') ? artifactoryUserName : getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME']`

On an related note, it would be much nicer if project.property returns `null` if not found instead of throwing exception.

Comment: Is it possible to define the `repository` part globally and have Gradle load credentials from shared location?

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ yes, definitely. you can use for example init scripts for that. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script