# Repository credentials work if they're hardcoded, but not if they're from gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, artifactory

### Problem

I am using Gradle and have my repository configurations, which require credentials. When I hardcode the username and password, everything works. When I try to store those same credentials in `gradle.properties` it doesn't.

### Background

The repository declarations in my `build.gradle` file essentially looks like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.example.com/libs/'
        credentials {
            username "myUsername"
            password "myPassword"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great and I can connect to my repository.

### What isn't working

As you can see above, the username and password is hardcoded. I want to make it configurable, so I follow [the advice in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25262562/531762) add the following properties to `gradle.properties`.

```
storedUsername = "myUsername"
storedPassword = "myPassword"
```

I then modify the `build.gradle` file to refer to those properties:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.example.com/libs/'
        credentials {
            username project.storedUsername
            password project.storedPassword 
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am suddenly unable to connect to my repository. When I check my server (Artifactory) logs, I am told that access was denied to a user without a name.

Both files are in the root directory as siblings. I've added `println "Username: ${project.repoUsername}"` to the `repositories{}` block, as well as both the `configurations {}` and `dependencies{}` blocks. They all correctly return the values they should.

I suspect this may be a scoping issue, but I can't figure out where it is. What can I do to have both repositories in an external file and credentials in `gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration is correct, but the issue is with `gradle.properties`. It is currently configured this way:

```
storedUsername = "myUsername"
storedPassword = "myPassword"
```

The issue is with the quotes. You don't have to surround the values on the right side of the equal signs as a string, so the quotes are treated as literals. In other words, the username you are sending to the server isn't `myUsername` but instead is `"myUsername"`, which presumably does not exist on the server.

Deleting the quotes will solve this issue:

```
storedUsername = myUsername
storedPassword = myPassword
```